# Will any Micro SD card work in an HTC Desire?

Tags: htc-desire, external-sd

I've bought my friend's HTC Desire off him, but it doesn't have an SD card. Should I buy just any Micro SD card, or do I need to get one specifically made for the HTC Desire? Is there anything else I need to know?

Comment: See also [Does the HTC Desire support 'microSDHC'?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/9861/), [Largest HTC Desire SD card?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/10308/) and [What size of SD card can an HTC Desire accomodate?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/18493/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The spec is simply listed ([on HTC's website](http://www.htc.com/us/products/desire-uscellular#tech-specs)) as such:

> **Memory**
>   ROM:  512 MB
>   RAM: 384 MB
>
> **Expansion slot**
>   8 GB microSD™ memory card (supports up to 32 GB)

The above link is for the US Cellular variant, but the [C Spire version](http://www.htc.com/us/products/desire-c-spire#tech-specs) has the same memory specs (the only real difference between variants is supported bands, AFAIK). [GSM Arena also reports](http://www.gsmarena.com/htc_desire-3077.php) "microSD up to 32GB". Generally speaking, Android devices support any SD card that properly complies with the SD spec. There are no "special" cards for devices - any will do.

Comment: Is it limited to SDHC though?  Presumably standard SD/SDSC cards will work but I'd be surprised if SDXC cards did.

Comment: @MatthewRead: 2.0 is backwards compatible with the original SD spec but not forward compatible with SDXC (so yes to your question). The spec info on Wikipedia specifically notes: "Host devices that accept SDHC cards are required to accept SDSC cards." (they provide [this citation](http://www.sdcard.org/developers/about/))

Comment: @MatthewRead: Or rather, "no" to your first question and "yes" to your second statement.